# Error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Parsing Tab Delimited text file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a script that reads a text file. The text that is read in is then used in an `SQL WHERE` clause to return data from a `SQL` db.

This works great, but I now have 2 columns of data in my text file, **separated by tabs**. And I want to use both columns of data in my `WHERE` clause, but I'm getting an

> `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1`.

I'm assuming it isn't splitting my tabbed data and for the life of me can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
public class Find_ImagePaths {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://myServer/myTable?useSSL=false", "UserName", "Password");
            
            Statement stmt1 = conn.createStatement(); {
                        
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\ImageExport\\SeriesDates.txt"));
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int Counter = 1;
            String line;
            String pid;
            String series;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                
            @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
               
                String [] token = line.split("\t");
                pid = token[0];
                series = token[1];{
            
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT c.ClientID AS CID, sopi.PATHINSTORAGE, date_format(se.SeriesDate, '%Y-%m-%d') AS SeriesDate, sopi.VISITSUBGROUPVALUE as Type FROM client c LEFT JOIN Study st ON c.ID = st.CLIENT_ID LEFT JOIN Series se ON st.ID = se.STUDY_ID LEFT JOIN SOPINSTANCE sopi ON se.ID = sopi.SERIES_ID WHERE c.ClientID = '"+pid+"' AND date_format(se.SeriesDate, '%Y-%m-%d') = '"+series+"'");

            while (rs1.next() ) {
                BufferedWriter bw = null;
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\ImageExport\\PathInStorage.txt", true));

                String[] array = new String [4];

                array[0] = rs1.getString("PATHINSTORAGE");
                array[1] = rs1.getString("CID");
                if (rs1.wasNull()) 
                    array[1] = "";
                array[2] = rs1.getString("SeriesDate");
                if (rs1.wasNull()) 
                    array[2] = "";
                array[3] = rs1.getString("Type");
                if (rs1.wasNull()) 
                    array[3] = "";

                bw.write(array[0]);
                bw.write("\t");
                bw.write(array[1]);
                bw.write("\t");
                bw.write(array[2]);
                bw.write("\t");
                bw.write(array[3]);
                    bw.newLine();
                    bw.close();     
            }
        }
    }
    reader.close();
    conn.close();                   
}}}
```

I am using `pid` and `series` in the `WHERE` clause of my sql statement. And I'm assuming my **error** is somewhere in here, as this is really the only section of code that I messed with after having the second column of data added to my text file:

```
 String [] token = line.split("\t");
 pid = token[0];
 series = token[1];
```

Comment: If it's tab delimited then why are you using line.split("@"); instead of line.split("\t") ?

Comment: Because I have no idea what I'm doing.  Self taught scripter. :(

Comment: Also I tried "\t" and it didn't work.  :-/

Comment: Sorry then, I should add that when you want to split by \t, since the argument of split is a regex, you need to double escape (first escape, escapes the \ so that the final string is a tab in the regex) 
ie: split("\\t")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split(String regex, int limit)` method to split by one or more spaces using below regex:

```
String [] token = line.split("\\s+");
```

The `+` quantifier means *one or more* matches.